# How to remove space below the UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

I'm creating app that contain tabBar. In tabBar 64*64 and 32*32 images sated to tabBarItem. But it will by default leave some space below of image. Like this,
[image]

How can I remove this space.

Thanx for help.

Comment: i am not clear with your image link.. please post the image here itself...

Comment: @Tony, i don't have enough reputation to post image. but thanx to somebody they posted the image. check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple document sayas tabbar Items mostly size if 30 * 30 see:-

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

so you just need to set your tabbar items icon with images is 48x32 pixels may be your issue getting fix.

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar images always line up with thetop of the tabbar.  If you want to make them have space above and below, you put that space in the icon.

So, you need to make your image taller and leave blank space on the top of your image.

The images should be 60x60 and 120x120, then they'll fit better.